# How to add link (href) on selected days in jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, jsfiddle

I need small help with this script:

```
var disabledDays = ["2013-9-5", "2013-9-13", "2013-9-28"];
var tips = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var m = date.getMonth(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            y = date.getFullYear();
        for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, disabledDays) != -1) {
                //return [false];
                return [true, 'highlight', tips[i]];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
});
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/VPzL7/

I cant figure out how to use same method as i delect days to add href link on these selected - highlighted days.

Comment: Why do you need to add an `href`? I would consider an alternate solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: calendar is site widget with highlighted days and description, i need to onclick redirect user to specific event detail page (*.php?eID=55).

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
td.highlight {
    border: none !important;
    padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;
    background: none !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
td.highlight a {
    background: #99dd73 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
    border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;
}
```

**jQUery**

```
var disabledDays = ["2013-9-20", "2013-9-24"];
var tips = ['some description1', 'some other description2'];
var hrefs = ['http://www.bbc.com/', 'http://www.cnn.com/'];

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var m = date.getMonth(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            y = date.getFullYear();
        for (var i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, disabledDays) != -1) {
                return [true, 'highlight', tips[disabledDays.indexOf(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d)]];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {        
        var date = new Date(dateText.slice(4)),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            y = date.getFullYear();        
        if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, disabledDays) != -1) {
            window.location = hrefs[disabledDays.indexOf((y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d))];
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/lacmop/XPTax/2/). Hope it will be helpfull for others..

Comment: You could use a single array of objects to keep your dates, tooltips, and links organized: `var data = [{date: '2013-10-10', tip: 'event1', link: 'http://example.com/1'}, {date: '2013-10-15', tip: 'event2', link: 'http://example.com/2'}];`

Comment: @Richard     

I think there's a slight error in the code:

`{ window.location = hrefs[disabledDays.indexOf((y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + (d+1)))]; }`

Seems to fix it

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it can be a solution. If you need to redirect to a page, use the `onSelect` option (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

```
var links = { "2013-09-05": 'http://my-website.com/event/world-domination' };

//...

    onSelect: function (dateString) {
        if ( links[ dateString ] )
          document.location.href = links[ dateString ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems jQueryUI doesn't provide a way to do this, but you could assign each "special" date a **second** class to handle it afterwards

```
return [true, 'date_'+String(y)+String(m)+String(d)+' highlight', tips[i]];
```

Then you could add listeners to trigger when each special date gets clicked

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.date_201385',function() {
 do something;
});
```